# Centralize capturing of errors in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, interceptor, jquery-callback

I have 15 `$.ajax` calls that are `JSONP`. I'm using this workaround to prevent javascript exceptions like:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery878937344363463463_8761219911121421 is not a function

I'm using this code in error callback to prevent it from showing up in console.

```
window[callbackname] = function() {
  window[callbackname] = null;
};
```

However, I think it's bad if I put that code in all my 15 AJAX calls. In AngularJS, we can intercept errors using `$httpProvider.interceptors`. This allows us to centralize logging rather than individually.

Does jQuery have a similar feature?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you'd want to do this or where it's applicable.

Comment: Why you have 15 `$.ajax` calls? Why not use one, with single error handling?

Comment: How would the jQuery assigned callback become undefined?

Comment: I'm not getting undefined. I do get the callback name. I didn't mention it was undefined

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you can use `$.ajaxSetup()` to set shared options that all of your `$.ajax` calls will use.

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

Comment: Reading the first line is making me worried :) "Description: Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is not recommended."

Comment: Ya, it is global! And global touches everything!